# Excel - Compare value to a filtered table and count the number of successful results

Tags: excel, count, compare, formula

I'm struggling with an excel formula.
The basics are quite simple.
First I have a normal table named "DataTable" and a column in it with header "Numbers" with numeric values. Secondly I have a cell with a numeric value.
I want to compare the numeric value in that cell with all the values in this table column, and see how many times the entries in this column table are smaller.
But a filter can be applied to the column/table so it's possible there are less rows after applying the filter. I only want to compare the cell value to the VISIBLE entries in this table to. And that's the part I struggle with. So the count result can change depending on what I filter on in the table. Anyone can help me with the formula for this?
Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like `SUBTOTAL` might be useful.

Comment: I know, I need it for sure to only use the subsection of the filtered table, but I can't get it right. I'm running into errors or results that are not correct.